# How to join two select count statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example If I have a table `'studentActivities'` in which every time a student does an activity it is recorded. Like so:

```
activity         countryofbirth    name    event_date
School Swimming  USA               Bob     5/21/2017 12:50
Park Swimming    Australia         Sarah   2/11/2017 19:50
Park Swimming    Australia         Sarah   2/13/2017 16:50
Park Running     USA               Bob     2/10/2017 11:50
School Tennis    USA               Bob     2/12/2017 11:50
NULL             USA               Jane    8/4/2016 13:30
```

I am trying to count the count distinct activities a student does based on if it is `In-School Actvity` or `Out-of-School Activity`.

This is distinguished by the `4` In-School Activities via:
`School Swimming, School Running, School Soccer, School Tennis`

What I would like to get is a table as so:

```
 Student_Name Country_of_Birth In-School_Activities Out_of_School_Activities
 Bob          USA              2                    1
 Sarah        Australia        0                    1
 Jane         USA              0                    0
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
 studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
 studentActivities.countryofbirth AS County_of_Birth],
 COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [In-School Activities]

 FROM studentActivities

 WHERE studentActivities.activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')

 GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth

 UNION

 SELECT 
 studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
 studentActivities.countryofbirth AS [County_of_Birth],
 COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [Out_of_School Activities]

 FROM studentActivities

 WHERE studentActivities.activity NOT IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')

 GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth
```

But this does not give me the result I want. How can I get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation with `count(distinct ...)`

```
select 
    Name
  , CountryOfBirth
  , InSchoolActivies    = count(distinct case when activity in ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis') then activity end)
  , OutOfSchoolActivies = count(distinct case when activity not in ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis') then activity end)
from StudentActivites
group by Name, CountryOfBirth
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EMUWU73595

returns: (After correcting Bob's Country of Birth in the sample data)

```
+-------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
| Name  | CountryOfBirth | InSchoolActivies | OutOfSchoolActivies |
+-------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
| Bob   | USA            |                2 |                   1 |
| Jane  | USA            |                0 |                   0 |
| Sarah | Australia      |                0 |                   1 |
+-------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Full Outer Join

```
 WITH InSchool AS (
 SELECT 
 studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
 studentActivities.countryofbirth ,
 COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [In-School Activities]
 FROM studentActivities
 WHERE studentActivities.activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
 GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth
 )
, OutOfSchool AS ( 
 SELECT 
 studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
 studentActivities.countryofbirth,
 COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [Out_of_School Activities]
 FROM studentActivities
 WHERE studentActivities.activity NOT IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
 GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth
 )
 SELECT
  COALESCE(InSchool.student_name, OutOfSchool.student_name) [Student_Name],
  COALESCE(InSchool.CountryOfBirth, OutOfSchool.CountryOfBirth) CountryOfBirth,
  COALESCE(InSchool.[In-School Activities],0) [In-School Activities],
  COALESCE(OutOfSchool.[Out_of_School Activities],0) [Out_of_School Activities]
 FROM InSchool
 FULL OUTER JOIN OutOfSchool
 ON InSchool.[student_name] = OutOfSchool.[Student_name]
 AND InSchool.CountryOfBirth = OutOfSchool.CountryOfBirth
```

Answer (score 1):

This what comes to my mind, I didn't verify, but this is how I got the task

```
SELECT 
 name AS [student_name],
 countryofbirth AS [Manufacturer],
 sum (activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')) as [In-School Activities],
 sum (activity NOT IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')) as [Out_of_School Activities]
 FROM (select distinct studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth, activity) x 
 GROUP BY  name, countryofbirth;
```

Comment: where'd you get the second alias - Manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a join (and not an union )

```
select a.[student_name], a.[student_name],  a.[In-School Activities], b.[Out_of_School Activities]
from ( 
  SELECT 
   studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
   studentActivities.countryofbirth AS [Manufacturer],
   COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [In-School Activities]
   FROM studentActivities
   WHERE studentActivities.activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
   GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth 
 ) a
 left  join (
   SELECT 
   studentActivities.name AS [student_name],
   studentActivities.countryofbirth AS [Manufacturer],
   COUNT (DISTINCT activity) as [Out_of_School Activities]
   FROM studentActivities
   WHERE studentActivities.activity NOT IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
   GROUP BY  studentActivities.name, studentActivities.countryofbirth 
 ) b on a.[student_name] = b.[student_name] and a.[Manufacturer] = b.[Manufacturer]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Case statement:

```
SELECT 
 Sa.name AS [student_name],
 Sa.countryofbirth,

 Sum(Case when sa.activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
 then 1 else 0 end) as In_school_Activities,

 Sum(Case when sa.activity IN ('School Swimming', 'School Running', 'School Soccer', 'School Tennis')
 then 0 else 1 end) as Out_of_school_Activities


 FROM (select distinct student_name, country _of_birth, activity from studentActivities) sa

 GROUP BY  sa.name, sa.countryofbirth
```

Note that in any non-trivial application, name can never be considered unique. If you have an identifier (and you should anytime you have Name), then it is better to group on that.

Answer (score 1):

A Pivot would solve this. I tested it with the data which you provided, and it worked as expected.

```
SELECT
    Name
    ,countryofbirth
    , [In-School Activity]
    ,[Out-of-School Activity]
FROM(
    SELECT
        name
        ,countryofbirth
        ,CASE Activity
            WHEN 'School Swimming' THEN 'In-School Activity'
            WHEN 'School Running'  THEN 'In-School Activity'
            WHEN 'School Soccer'   THEN 'In-School Activity'
            WHEN 'School Tennis'   THEN 'In-School Activity'        
            ELSE 'Out-of-School Activity'
        END class
    FROM studentactivities
    WHERE Activity IS NOT NULL
)AS base
PIVOT(
    COUNT (CLASS)
    FOR CLASS IN ([In-School Activity],[Out-of-School Activity])
)AS Pivoted
```

Answer (score 1):

Bob has 2 countryofbirth locations.  Is that 2 separate Bobs or is it an error?  I didn't test this so it might not be 100% accurate, but I prefer a common table expression:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS [student_name]
    ,countryofbirth
    ,activity
    ,CASE 
        WHEN activity IN (
                'School Swimming'
                ,'School Running'
                ,'School Soccer'
                ,'School Tennis'
                )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS [In-school_activity_count]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN activity IS NOT NULL
            AND activity NOT IN (
                'School Swimming'
                ,'School Running'
                ,'School Soccer'
                ,'School Tennis'
                )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS [Out-of-school_activity_count]
FROM studentActivities
)
SELECT student_name
,countryofbirth
,SUM([In-school_activity_count]) AS [In-School_Activities]
,SUM([Out-of-school_activity_count]) AS [Out_of_School_Activities]
FROM cte
GROUP BY student_name
,countryofbirth
```

Answer (score 1):

The below is simple and works :

```
select name,countryofbirth,sum(schoolflag) as 
In_School_Activity,sum(nonschool) Out_Of_School_Activity
from 
 (
 select activity,name,countryofbirth,
 case when activity like 'School%' then 1 else 0 end as schoolflag ,
 case when activity not like 'School%' then 1 else 0 end as nonschool
 from schoolactivity
 )a
group by name,countryofbirth
```